# WSDL contract list occuring with numbers

Tags: soap, xsd, wsdl, element, contract

When I define the fields of a contract in XSD I define a list field with maxOccurs= and minOccurs>0.

Can i declare the XSD in such a way that when the request is received the fields with occurs have occurance number?
e.g.

I hope i make my self clear.

```
<xsd:complexType name="FieldNameType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="FieldName" type="FieldNameType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="8"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

and when the request is send i get something like:

```
<FieldName_1></FieldName_1>
<FieldName_2></FieldName_2>
<FieldName_3></FieldName_3>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around! As i saw i can iterate through the same nodes in an XSLT file.